# Change Button Colour By Changing Button Style

Tags: android, xml, button, colors, diacritics

Good day.

I tried changing the button colour as I do not wish it to be the accent colour. Thus, I tried changing the button style. Below is my code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/enterButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/enter_button"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sohere_font_small"
    style="@style/NewButtonStyle"
    android:enabled="true"/>

  <style name="NewButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@drawable/selector_button_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/selector_button_text_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_color</item>
</style>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:color="@color/primary_color" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="@color/default_disabled_button_colour" />
</selector>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:color="@color/white_color" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="@color/default_hint_text_color" />
</selector>
```

However the button colour does not change until I modify my code to:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/enterButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/enter_button"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sohere_font_small"
    **android:theme="@style/NewButtonStyle"**
    android:enabled="true"/>
```

Is there any way I can change the button colour by setting the button style changing the theme?

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

For Styling your Button you can use this :

Go to the drawable folder and make a xml (e.g. button.xml) file called style which contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  

    <item>
         <shape>
             <gradient android:startColor="#449def" android:endColor="#2f6699" android:angle="270" />
             <stroke   android:width="1px"          android:color="#000000" />  
                <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
                android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>       
              <padding  android:left="10dp"  android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
         </shape>  
   </item> 

</selector>
```

This is my code you can make the necessary changes you want

Now call it in your layout xml (mainactivity.xml) like this

```
android:background="@drawable/button.xml"
```

Now to change the font color and style you can use the following which comes as part of the styles.xml in the values folder

```
<style name="buttonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Now call this in the layout xml (mainactivity.xml) like this

```
  style="@style/buttonStyle"
```

The final code is:

```
<Button
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
 android:text="@string/edit"
 android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
 android:background="@drawable/button.xml"
 style="@style/buttonStyle"
/>
```

Hope this helps :)